# Get only data that are repeated any one of the given year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the Raw Data. I want only those event which will repeat in given set of list of years. Eg [2012,2013]. So now it should only get data if event is repeated in one of the given year in the list.

```
    Event   Year
Event 1     2012
Event 1     2013
Event 1     2014
Event 1     2015
Event 2     2012
Event 2     2013
Event 3     2014
Event 3     2015
Event 3     2014
Event 4     2012
Event 4     2015
Event 5     2013
```

I want below output.

```
    Event   Year
Event 1     2012
Event 1     2013
Event 1     2014
Event 1     2015
Event 2     2012
Event 2     2013
Event 4     2012
Event 4     2015
Event 5     2013
```

Comment: Why `Event 4` is not in the output while `Event 1` is?

Comment: I have edited the question Event 4 has to be in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby` and `filter`

```py
lst = [2012, 2013]
out = df.groupby('Event').filter(lambda g: g['Year'].isin(lst).any())
```

```
print(out)

      Event  Year
0   Event 1  2012
1   Event 1  2013
2   Event 1  2014
3   Event 1  2015
4   Event 2  2012
5   Event 2  2013
9   Event 4  2012
10  Event 4  2015
11  Event 5  2013
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think two `isin` operations:

```
valid_events = df.loc[df.Year.isin([2012,2013]), 'Event']
df.loc[df.Event.isin(valid_events)]
```

Output:

```
      Event  Year
0   Event 1  2012
1   Event 1  2013
2   Event 1  2014
3   Event 1  2015
4   Event 2  2012
5   Event 2  2013
9   Event 4  2012
10  Event 4  2015
11  Event 5  2013
```